# dll file or .exe file is missing

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, executable

I my desktop application, I had created a form and executed it, it was successfully executed but even after modifying the form the previous form was being used. For that I have deleted all the dll and .exe file created in the debug folder for the previous form. but now it is showing the following error...

bin/debug .exe file is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to compile it again to regenerate the dlls

Comment: @Srivastava: I assume you solved the "above error?" What made you accept this answer when you said it didn't work for you? Please explain what you did to fix the problem (post an answer?) so that anyone else who has the same problem may be able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

**First, make sure that you are in *Debug* mode, rather than Release mode:**

1. Select your project in the Solution Explorer.
2. From the "View" menu, select "Property Pages."
3. If you're using C# or F#, click the "Build" or "Debug" tab. If you're using VB.NET, click the "Compile" or "Debug" tab. If you're using C++, click the "Configuration Properties" tab.
4. In the "Configuration" drop-down list, select "Debug."

   (If you have any trouble with this, check out the [full how-to guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx) on MSDN.)

**Then, clean and rebuild your solution:**

1. From the "Build" menu, select "Clean Solution."
2. Again from the "Build" menu, select "Rebuild Solution."
3. Finally, from the "Debug" menu, select "Start Debugging" (or press <kbd>F5</kbd>).

**If that still doesn't work:**

- Open the form you edited in design-view (without running the application, as if you were going to make further changes to the form) and make sure that your changes were actually saved.
- Make sure that your code is calling the correct (updated) form. Check the name of the form you're asking the application to show, and make sure it matches the form you want to display.
- Make sure that you don't have two copies of the same form. You might have accidentally modified a second version, and your code is still showing the original version.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting that error and doing all of the solutions mentioned but it still wasn't working. I discovered that my anti-virus program was containing my .exe file so the program wasn't reaching it. After turning my anti-virus program off, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you marked to build the project in configuration manager:

[image]